# like_escape notice when using LIKE in meta query

Tags: meta-query

When I try to use LIKE or NOT LIKE as a compare value in a WP meta query, I get the following errors in my debug logs:

```
PHP Notice:  like_escape is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.0.0! Use wpdb::esc_like() instead. in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 3830
```

Is there something incorrect about this query that is causing the error?

```
$myquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'my-cpt'
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'meta_key' => 'my_timezone_meta_key',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'my_timezone_meta_key',
                'value' => 'EST',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )

        )
    ));

echo "<h3>found posts:" . $myquery->found_posts . "</h3>";
```

Comment: well, obviously it is not called by core, so it comes from one of your plugins. you just need to do a stack trace debug and fix

Comment: are you saying a plugin is pre-empting a standard wp query and that I should look for a conflict there?

Comment: yes, will suspect a "security" plugin to do such stupid things, but maybe it is a caching one.... obviously I am just guessing, do a stack trace and debug the issue

Comment: well I found the line of code in a plugin (you were right) causing the error, but I guess there is nothing to do about it, because it (seems to be) properly checking for the existence of the function for backward compatibility before running the correct updated function if it exists. It would be nice if this check did not raise the notice, but I guess that is impossible.

Comment: the plugin author should fix the code as if code was correct there would have been no error. The problem with notices like that is that the code might actually work properly but they pollute the error log and make it harder to notice actual issues

Comment: except that this error is generated by WP itself when the plugin is just checking if the old function exists (I assume for backward compatibility) and using the newer and correct one if available. Maybe instead they should have checked the version of WP itself, and THEN called the old function thus avoiding the error notice.

Comment: What Mark is trying to say is that threre should not be any warning by checking existence of a function. So the plugin author does it the wrong way thus there is the warning